# That bookmark *does* exist

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to get to a specific point in my Word document from excel VBA. My ultimate goal is to copy new text into the bottom of the document.

So I put a bookmark at the bottom of my document and did this:

```
wDoc.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Name:="TemplatePage"
```

And it tells me "That bookmark does not exist." Which is funny, because it clearly does. It says the same thing about all my bookmarks.

This does not give me an error, instead it doesn't do anything:

```
wDoc.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, which:=wdgotofirst
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: I'm going to just leave this here (since we're on the topic of GOTO's) http://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something obvious here?

IMO you are missing something, but the use of the word "Goto" can create the wrong impression.

.Goto actually makes the object that you specify "goto" the specified location. So if that object is a range, you shouldn't expect the Selection to change.

The other thing is that you have to omit the "which" parameter in this case. I don't know how you could determine that from the documentation - it's a question of trial and error with some of these range-related things.

Since the range implied by wDoc or wDoc.Content won't change anyway, you will lose any useful information immediately by executing the .Goto as a command. If you use it as a function, you get a range, so you can use, e.g.

```
Dim r As Word.Range
Set r = wDoc.Goto(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Which:=wdGoToFirst)
Debug.print r.start, r.end
```

Or if you want to select the resulting range, you can use

```
r.Select
```

But if you want to set a range

```
Dim r As Word.Range
Set r = wDoc.Bookmarks("TemplatePage)
```

is (IMO) simpler and you already have the code that actually selects it if that is what you need.

Comment: So I see where you're going here, but clearly I don't understand the concept of a "range" in this context. Is this something similar to selection, being a start and end point, but doesn't actually select the text?

Comment: Yes, it is as you say. The Selection is really what it says - the user can change the Selection in various ways, and code can too. A Range also "covers" an area of the document, but it is really an object created and maintained programmatically. You can have more than one at once. Changing the location of a range does not have any impact on the display, so code that works via ranges typically runs faster and with less flicker than code that uses the Selection. Although the Selection object and a Range object have similar properties, they do differ in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently the GoTo simply doesn't work. I tried all sorts of variations on Page, Section, Bookmark, they either did nothing, gave errors, or even moved to the wrong place (selected text in the header!)

Instead, you can try:

```
wDoc.Bookmarks("TemplatePage").Select
```

Works like a champ.